# Re-order PHP array by middle key as start (Circular Sorting)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, key

very basic question however I have had some trouble finding the answers on PHP.NET.

I have the following array:

```
Array (

[1] => Array
    (
        [1] => 4
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 5
        [4] => 3
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [5] => 2
        [6] => 8
        [7] => 7
        [8] => 6
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [9] => 10
        [10] => 9
        [11] => 12
        [12] => 11
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [13] => 15
        [14] => 16
        [15] => 14
        [16] => 13
    )

)
```

I want the array to be re-ordered so that the key number 3 in the first series of the array becomes the first, then the rest to be re-ordered from there to eventually get the result of:

```
Array (

[3] => Array
    (
        [9] => 10
        [10] => 9
        [11] => 12
        [12] => 11
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [13] => 15
        [14] => 16
        [15] => 14
        [16] => 13
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [1] => 4
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 5
        [4] => 3
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [5] => 2
        [6] => 8
        [7] => 7
        [8] => 6
    )

)
```

I am looking for a way to do this so I can define the array, then the first level key I need to sort by, and then it will return the array in this way.

The standard PHP keys didn't seem to offer something like this, so it would be good to be able to have a separate function such as $newArray = reorder_array($array, $key);

I don't require any sorting of the second level, only the initial 4 main / first level array sections.

You help is greatly appreciated as I have been sitting on this one for awhile without a clear and simple solution.

Comment: have you tried asort() function ?

Comment: I fail to understand the sorting logic you want to do, sorry. Please explain the logic what you want to achieve (eg: what exactly makes an element go up or down, etc).

Comment: @Calimero circular sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You re-ordering can be simply implemented with one `foreach` loop, like:

```
function reorderArray($array, $key)
{
    $found = false;
    foreach($array as $k=>$v)
    {
        $found = $found || $k===$key;
        if(!$found)
        {
            unset($array[$k]);
            $array[$k] = $v;
        }
        //else break can be added for performance issues
    }
    return $array;
}
```

with usage

```
$array=[1=>'foo', 4=>'bar', 9=>'baz', 'test'=>51];
var_dump(reorderArray($array, 9));
var_dump(reorderArray($array, 'test'));
var_dump(reorderArray($array, 'no_such_key'));//original array in result
```

-check [this](http://3v4l.org/sRWVK) demo. If keys are consecutive numerics, however, this can be easily implemented with [`array_slice()`](https://www.php.net/array_slice) calls.